# Add custom compile time checks to Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.11

Suppose I have the following Scala code:

```
sealed trait Foo
sealed trait Bar
object Foo1 extends Foo
object Foo2 extends Foo
object Foo3 extends Foo
object Bar1 extends Bar
object Bar2 extends Bar
object Bar3 extends Bar
case class Hello(foo:Foo, bar:Bar)

val a = Hello(Foo1, Bar2) // allowed
val b = Hello(Foo2, Bar2) // suppose not allowed
```

I need to catch at compile time if any incompatible combination is applied to `Hello`. Suppose only the following combinations are allowed: `(Foo1, Bar1)`, `(Foo1, Bar2)`, `(Foo2, Bar3)` and `(Foo3, Bar3)`.

Is it possible to test this during compile time? 
I realize that [plugins](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/140) and [macros](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/12/starting-with-scala-macros-a-short-tutorial/) may allow me to do this. Some hints would be appreciated. The above tutorials seem outdated for the latest versions of Scala (2.11.x), so pointers to other tutorials would also be great.

In the real example, there are about 10 instances of `Foo` and `Bar`, giving a total of 100 combinations, about half of them invalid. Furthermore, the valid combinations could change arbitrarily in future.

**EDIT**

Actual problem is bit more complex. The `Hello` method takes in `Seq` as follows:

```
case class Hello(foos:Seq[Foo], bars:Seq[Bar])
```

Examples of complex criteria are:

1. If `foos` contain `Foo1` then `bars` cannot have `Bar1`.
2. `foos` cannot contain `Foo1` and `Foo3` together.

Code examples:

```
Hello(Seq(Foo1), Seq(Bar2, Bar3)) // valid 
Hello(Seq(Foo1, Foo3), Seq(Bar1)) // invalid due to rule 2
```

Comment: In addition to @DaunnC's answer, there's an explanation of the technique [here](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/).

Comment: Are there any rules which determine which combinations are valid and which aren't?

Comment: @MilesSabin No. The valid combinations are quite arbitrary.. but there are certain rules.. See my edit above.

Comment: Do you know the contents of those sequences at compile time? Ie. could you represent them as tuples rather than as `Seq`s?

Comment: The update looks helpful, however, the comment on the second line looks incorrect: rule 2 is satisfied, and it's rule 1 which isn't.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo.  Fixed it

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick with types, not sure it is very beautiful (not beautiful at all), and you have to write lots of such rules manually, but mb you don't need to use heavy plugins / libs:

```
trait Validator[F, S] { }
object Validator {
    implicit object firstPair extends Validator[Foo1.type, Bar1.type]
    implicit object secondPair extends Validator[Foo1.type, Bar2.type]
    implicit object thirdPair extends Validator[Foo2.type, Bar3.type]
    implicit object fourthPair extends Validator[Foo3.type, Bar3.type]
}

case class Hello[F <: Foo, S <: Bar](foo: F, bar: S)(implicit v: Validator[F, S])

val a = Hello(Foo1, Bar2) // allowed
val b = Hello(Foo2, Bar2) // break in compile time
```

Comment: This is absolutely the right way to go ... it would be completely inappropriate to uses macros or plugins for something which has a straightforward solution in first-class Scala.

Comment: Its not that ugly either. Seems to be the easiest way to go.

Comment: However, I'd like to use plugins for that. The actual situation is more complex, because `Foo` and `Bar` themselves are composed of other types and the `Hello` class takes arrays as parameters.

Comment: Then post an example that more accurately reflects your question. Macros and plugins are solutions of last resort.

Comment: @ Miles Sabin I have modified my example