# Scala: how to work with collections of types?

Tags: scala

I am writing by hand a recursive-descent parser for a small language. In my lexer I have:

```
trait Token{def position:Int}
trait Keyword  extends Token
trait Operator extends Token

case class Identifier(position:Int, txt:String) extends Token
case class If        (position:Int)             extends Keyword
case class Plus      (position:Int)             extends Operator
/* etcetera; one case class per token type */
```

My parser works well, and now I would like to incorporate some error recovery: replacing, inserting or discarding tokens until some synchronization point.

For that, it would be handy to have a function that, in invalid Scala, would look something like this

```
def scanFor(tokenSet:Set[TokenClass], lookahead:Int) = {
  lexer.upcomingTokens.take(lookahead).find{ token =>
    tokenSet.exists(tokenClass => token.isInstanceOf[tokenClass])
  }
}
```

which I would call, for example: `scanFor(Set(Plus, Minus, Times, DividedBy), 4)`

However `TokenClass`, of course, is not a valid type, and I don't know how to create the previous set.

As alternatives:

1. I could just create a new trait and make all the token classes in the token set I want to check against extend that trait, and then just do an `instanceOf` check against that trait. However, I may have several of those sets, which could make them hard to name, and the code hard to maintain later on.
2. I could create isXXX:Token=>Boolean functions, and make sets of those, but it seems unelegant

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361147/add-custom-compile-time-checks-to-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually recommend, if there are only a handful of such combinations, using an additional trait.  It's easy to write and understand, and it will be fast at runtime.  It's not really so bad to say

```
case class Plus(position: Int)
extends Operator with Arithmetic with Precedence7 with Unary
```

But there are a wide range of alternatives.

If you don't mind a finicky manual maintenance process and need something really fast, defining an ID number (which you must manually keep distinct) for each token type will allow you to use `Set[Int]` or `BitSet` or even just a `Long` to select those classes you like.  You can then do set operations (union, intersection) to build up these selectors from each other.  It's not hard to write unit tests to help make the finicky bit a little more reliable.  If you can at least manage to list all your types:

```
val everyone = Seq(Plus, Times, If /* etc */)
assert(everyone.length == everyone.map(_.id).toSet.size)
```

So you shouldn't be too alarmed by this approach if you decide the performance and composability are essential.

You can also write custom extractors that can (more slowly) pull out the right subset of tokens by pattern matching.  For example,

```
object ArithOp {
  def unapply(t: Token): Option[Operator] = t match {
    case o: Operator => o match {
      case _: Plus | _: Minus | _: Times | _: DividedBy => Some(o)
      case _ => None
    }
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

will give you `None` if it's not the right type of operation.  (In this case, I'm assuming there's no parent other than `Operator`.)

Finally, you could probably express your types as unions and HLists and pick them out that way using Shapeless, but I don't have experience personally doing that with a parser, so I'm not sure of what difficulties you might encounter.

Comment: Thanks. I really like the id idea. Since they are all case classes, I could also use their hashCode

Comment: @Eduardo - You want to be sure to avoid collisions in the ID, which means that you can't rely upon a computed value like `hashCode`.  You could use `getClass.getName`, but that throws away much of the speed benefit from using ID numbers.